# Best mysql way to search through a string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a messages field in my database, I want to search for a particular string in the users messages in the fastest way. Since the user has got many messages, the process might be slow.
This is the sql query that I have so far:

```
$result=mysql_query("
          SELECT message_content 
          FROM `messages` AS ms
          INNER JOIN users1 AS us ON us.user_id=ms.user_id
          WHERE us.user_id=".$user_id." AND  message_content LIKE '%".$string_to_search."%'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Is there a way to speed up the search?

Comment: Considering the requirements you have, your search seems fine to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String searching is an inherently problematic venture with databases. Using `LIKE` is the most portable way to do it; it certainly searches your strings. That implies that it reads *every* record and scans for the given substring, which is the very slowest way you can search a database.

An alternative in MySQL is to use [FULLTEXT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) searches, which are index-driven but have a number of restrictions imposed on them. It's better, but it's not the sort of thing you'd want to build a search engine on.

On the other hand, projects like [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) ARE in fact designed for running a search engine, and do it very well. Sphinx ties pretty well into MySQL and was built specifically for solving this problem. It offers very good search accuracy and performance, so if you're doing anything serious, it's the way to go.

Comment: and use jquery + php mysql. It's a little fast then php and mysql.. User don't see any page reloaded if you query execute time is big. USABILITY